# How to display ellipsis to user

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django beginner. I have posts of users I follow and those who follows me,and I want to display different ellipsis ontop of other users post and not mine. For example if user A is friend user B, I want an ellipsis to be displayed only in user B post. What i tried doesn't give me what I wanted:

```
{% for post in all_images %} 
{% if post.user == request.user %}
<i fas fa-ellipsis></i>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %} 

class Image(models.Model):
    imageuploader_profile=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) 

class FriendRequest(models.Model) :
    from_user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='from_user') 
    to_user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='to_user') 

def home(request)
    all_images = Image objects.filter(
    Q(imageuploader_profile=request.user)|
    Q(imageuploader_profile__from_user__to_user=request.user)|
    Q(imageuploader_profile__to_user__from_user=request.user))
context = {'all_images': all_images }

{% for post in all_images %} 

.... my codes here..... 

<i class="fas fa-ellipsis"></i>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you add your models and your complete view to your post? And please explain what result your code gives you.

Comment: @Chris.. i have updated my model and my views is pointing to all the post uploaded. What I mean is that when user A is friend user B, all post of user A and B will be displayed on the homepage, that in my views I have done correctly. But I want an ellipsis icon to display at the top of user B post and not on user A post, because I want to add a drop down option for user B post, like: delete post, hide post, block user, report user. I do not want user A post to have an ellipsis icon with option.

Comment: In you example: Is user A the user who requests the view, i.E request.user == User A?

Comment: Yes, user A is me, user B is other user

Comment: I think the check in your template should be ```{% if post.imageuploader_profile != request.user %}``` to place ```<i class="fas fa.eliipsis"></i>``` everywhere except in the part for the request.user

Comment: @Chris.. You are correct. It worked. And if I want otherwise it would be {% if not post.imageuploader_profile != request.user %}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted your check is refering to a field in `post` which does not exist (`user`).

The check in your template should be

```
{% if post.imageuploader_profile != request.user %}
```

to place `<i class="fas fa.eliipsis"></i>` everywhere except in the part for `request.user`.

In order to place something in the part for the `request.user` your check would be

```
{% if post.imageuploader_profile == request.user %}
```

You can also use the clause you posted in the comment but this would be a double negation which is harder to read ;-)